# JAXB- @XmlMixed usage for reading @XmlValue and @XmlElement

Tags: jaxb

I saw a similar question being posted here, yet it did not help me solve the problem so I am posting my question here to see if someone can modify my code to make it work.

Question: How to access mixed content String value and save it in setPhrase(String value) method?

caption.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tt xmlns="link1" xmlns:prefix2="link2" prefix1:att1="att1">
    <head>
        <styling>
            <style prefix1:att1="att1" prefix2:att2="att2" prefix2:att3="att3" prefix2:att4="att4" />
        </styling>
        <layout />
    </head>
    <body xmlns:prefix3="link3">
        <div prefix1:att1="att1" prefix1:att2="att2">
            <prefix3:info att1="att1" att2="att2" />
            <p att1="att1" att2="att2" att3="att3">
                <prefix3:status att1="att1" att2="att2" />
                Hello World.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</tt>
```

Caption.java:

```
package com;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRefs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlMixed;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "p")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "att1", "att2", "att3", "phrase", "subelement"})
public class Caption {
    private String  att1;
    private String  att2;
    private String  att3;
    private String  phrase;
    private Subelement subelement = new Subelement();

   @XmlMixed
   public void setPhrase(String value)
   {
      this.phrase = value;
   }
   public String getPhrase()
   {
      return phrase;
   }

   @XmlElementRefs({@XmlElementRef(name = "subelement", type = Subelement.class)})
   @XmlMixed
   public void setSubelement(Subelement subelement )
   {
      this.subelement = subelement;
   }
   public Subelement getSubelement()
   {
      return subelement;
   }

   @XmlAttribute
   public void setAtt1( String att1 )
   {
      this.att1 = att1;
   }
   public String getAtt1()
   {
      return att1;
   }

   @XmlAttribute
   public void setAtt2( String att2 )
   {
      this.att2 = att2;
   }
   public String getAtt2()
   {
      return att2;
   }

   @XmlAttribute
   public void setAtt3( String att3 )
   {
      this.att3 = att3;
   }
   public String getAtt3()
   {
      return att3;
   }
}
```

After using JAXB unmarshall and marshall I am able to get everything converted into and object and saved accorderling, except for the actual phrase "Hello World.". I know I must use some sort of @XmlMixed for this complex element but I cannot figure it out.

My current output.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tt xmlns="link1" xmlns:prefix2="link2" prefix1:att1="att1">
    <head>
        <styling>
            <style prefix1:att1="att1" prefix2:att2="att2" prefix2:att3="att3" prefix2:att4="att4" />
        </styling>
        <layout />
    </head>
    <body xmlns:prefix3="link3">
        <div prefix1:att1="att1" prefix1:att2="att2">
            <prefix3:info att1="att1" att2="att2" />
            <p att1="att1" att2="att2" att3="att3">
                <prefix3:status att1="att1" att2="att2" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</tt>
```

Desire output.xml: (same as caption.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tt xmlns="link1" xmlns:prefix2="link2" prefix1:att1="att1">
    <head>
        <styling>
            <style prefix1:att1="att1" prefix2:att2="att2" prefix2:att3="att3" prefix2:att4="att4" />
        </styling>
        <layout />
    </head>
    <body xmlns:prefix3="link3">
        <div prefix1:att1="att1" prefix1:att2="att2">
            <prefix3:info att1="att1" att2="att2" />
            <p att1="att1" att2="att2" att3="att3">
                <prefix3:status att1="att1" att2="att2" />
                Hello World.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</tt>
```

Thanks in advance to any help I may get to access this value and save it in setPhrase(String value) method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question with an example:

**input.xml**

We will use the following XML document for this example.  The `root` element has mixed content.  Having mixed conent means that text nodes can appear mixed in with the elements.  Since more than one text node can appear a unary property isn't a good fit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <root/>
    Hello
    <root/>
    World
    <root/>
</root>
```

**Demo**

The following code will be used in to read in the XML to object form and then write it back to XML.

```
package forum10940267;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum10940267/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**USE CASE #1 - One List to Hold Mixed Content**

`@XmlMixed` is most often used to with another annotation, so that the resulting `List` contains both element and text content.  One advantage of this is that order is maintained so that the document can be round tripped.

```
package forum10940267;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private List<Object> mixedContent = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @XmlElementRef(name="root", type=Root.class)
    @XmlMixed
    public List<Object> getMixedContent() {
        return mixedContent;
    }

    public void setMixedContent(List<Object> mixedContent) {
        this.mixedContent = mixedContent;
    }

}
```

**Output**

The output matches the input.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <root/>
    Hello
    <root/>
    World
    <root/>
</root>
```

**USE CASE #2 - Separate List for Mixed Content**

You can can also introduce a separate list property for the text content.

```
package forum10940267;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private List<Object> mixedContent = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private List<String> text;

    @XmlElementRef(name="root", type=Root.class)
    public List<Object> getMixedContent() {
        return mixedContent;
    }

    public void setMixedContent(List<Object> mixedContent) {
        this.mixedContent = mixedContent;
    }

    @XmlMixed
    public List<String> getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(List<String> text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

**Output**

The output no longer matches the input.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <root/>
    <root/>
    <root/>

    Hello

    World

</root>
```

**USE CASE #3 - String Property for Text Content**

Since text nodes can occur multiple times in mixed content, a non-List property isn't a good fit and it appears as though the `@XmlMixed` annotation is being ignored.

```
package forum10940267;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private List<Object> mixedContent = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private String text;

    @XmlElementRef(name="root", type=Root.class)
    public List<Object> getMixedContent() {
        return mixedContent;
    }

    public void setMixedContent(List<Object> mixedContent) {
        this.mixedContent = mixedContent;
    }

    @XmlMixed
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <root/>
    <root/>
    <root/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Blaise. I was able to get it to work. Also do you know a way to make sure the root prefix (prefix1:att1="att1") is the last thing shown? I want it to appear in tt element last, after namespaces (xmlns="link1" xmlns:prefix2="link2").