# how do i set value of a Jaxb XMLelement?

Tags: jaxb

my question is: from the `xml` scheme :

```
<topnode>
    topNodeValue
   <bottomnode/> 
</topnode>
```

generated class with Jaxb looks like

```
class topnode {
    List<bottomnode> bottomnodeList;
}
```

Which does not generate the value field to set value for topnode.

How can I acheive this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the contents of an element contain both character and element data it is called mixed content.  In [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) this is mapped with the `@XmlMixed` annotation like:

```
class topnode {
    @XmlMixed
    String text;

    List<bottomnode> bottomnodeList;
}
```

The use of mixed content can be tricky, since you may get unexpected results due to text nodes used for formatting.  For a more detailed explanation see the following answer to a similar question.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11099303/383861

Answer (score 0):

For text nodes, use `@XmlValue` annotation. Something like this:

```
class topnode {

    @XmlValue
    String topNodeValue;

    List<bottomnode> bottomnodeList;

}
```

As a suggestion, try to respect java naming standards and if it doesn't match the xml elements use the `name` attribute of the `@Xml...` annotations.

Comment: since the `bottomnodeList` property maps to an XML element you will get an exception if you try to use `@XmlElement` instead.  The OP is trying to map mixed content, so `@XmlMixed` should be used instead of `@XmlValue`.  The following should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11099303/383861

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Thanks! I didn't know about `@XmlMixed`, since I never needed it. I think you should put this comment as answer, you'll definitely have an up from me.