# JAXB returning null

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I had read a couple JAXB tutorials and I tried to implement my own.  I am getting null back. I am unsure why I am getting null. 
Here is my XML Document. I am sorry in advance for how long this post is with mostly code. I am just not sure if I am implementing JAXB correctly or not.

```
<EZMAXMOBILE_OFFLINE_PROPERTIES synctime="">

<ENTITY_DEFS>
    <ENTITY name="WORKORDER">
        <INDEXES>           
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_1">WORKORDERID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_2">WONUM, SITEID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_3">ASSETNUM, SITEID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_WO_4">LOCATION, SITEID</INDEX>
        </INDEXES>      
        <COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN autokey="Y" autokeyprefix="LOCAL" parentkeycol="PARENTID" uniquekey="Y">WORKORDERID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN displaykey="Y" autokey="Y" autokeyprefix="OFFLN">WONUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PARENTID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PARENT</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>DESCRIPTION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LONGDESCRIPTION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LOCATION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ASSETNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PERSONGROUP</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>CREWID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>SUPERVISOR</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LEAD</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PHONE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>REPORTEDBY</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>REPORTDATE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>STATUS</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>STATUSDATE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>WOPRIORITY</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>WORKTYPE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>FAILURECODE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PROBLEMCODE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ISTASK</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ORIGRECORDID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ESTDUR</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>OBSERVATION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>MEASUREMENTVALUE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>TASKID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>SITEID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ORGID</COLUMN>
        </COLUMNS>
        <INIT_ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getMyWorkOrderListJson.action</ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getMyTaskWorkOrderListJson.action</ACTION>
        </INIT_ACTION>
        <DELTA_ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getDeltaMyWorkOrderListJson.action</ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getDeltaMyTaskWorkOrderListJson.action</ACTION>
        </DELTA_ACTION>
        <SYNC_ACTIONS transentityname="WORKORDER" transentitykey="WORKORDERID">
            <ACTION name="INSERT" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="addWorkOrder"/>
            <ACTION name="EDIT" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="editWorkOrder"/>
            <ACTION name="INSERT_TASK" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="addTaskWorkOrder"/>
            <ACTION name="UPDATE_STATUS" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="updateWorkOrderStatus"/>
            <ACTION name="UPDATE_TASK" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="updateWorkOrderTask"/>
            <ACTION name="UPDATE_TASK_STATUS" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="updateWorkOrderStatus"/>
            <ACTION name="EMM_FILE_UPLOAD"/>
        </SYNC_ACTIONS>
    </ENTITY>
    <ENTITY name="LABTRANS">
        <INDEXES>           
            <INDEX name="IDX_LT_1">WONUM, SITEID, LABORCODE</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_LT_2">WONUM, SITEID, LABORCODE, TIMERSTATUS</INDEX>
        </INDEXES>
        <COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN displaykey="Y" uniquekey="Y" autokey="Y" autokeyprefix="LT">LABTRANSID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>WORKORDERID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>WONUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LABORCODE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>CRAFT</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>REGULARHRS</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PREMIUMPAYCODE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PREMIUMPAYHOURS</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>STARTDATE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>FINISHDATE</COLUMN>             
            <COLUMN>TRANSTYPE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>TIMERSTATUS</COLUMN>                
            <COLUMN>SITEID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ORGID</COLUMN>
        </COLUMNS>
        <INIT_ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getMyLabTransJson.action</ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getMyTaskLabTransJson.action</ACTION>
        </INIT_ACTION>
        <DELTA_ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getDeltaMyLabTransJson.action</ACTION>
            <ACTION>offline/getDeltaMyTaskLabTransJson.action</ACTION>
        </DELTA_ACTION>
        <SYNC_ACTIONS transentityname="WORKORDER" transentitykey="WORKORDERID">
            <ACTION name="INSERT" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="addLabTrans"/>
            <ACTION name="START_TIMER" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="startTimer"/>
            <ACTION name="STOP_TIMER" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="stopTimer"/>
        </SYNC_ACTIONS>
    </ENTITY>           
    <ENTITY name="MATUSETRANS">
        <INDEXES>           
            <INDEX name="IDX_MT_1">WONUM, SITEID</INDEX>
        </INDEXES>
        <COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN displaykey="Y" uniquekey="Y">MATUSETRANSID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>WORKORDERID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>WONUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>DESCRIPTION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LINETYPE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ITEMNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>QUANTITY</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>UNITCOST</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>TRANSDATE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ISSUETYPE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ISSUETO</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>BINNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LOTNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>STORELOC</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ASSETNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LOCATION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>SITEID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ORGID</COLUMN>
        </COLUMNS>
        <INIT_ACTION>offline/getMyMatUseTransJson.action</INIT_ACTION>
        <DELTA_ACTION>offline/getDeltaMyMatUseTransJson.action</DELTA_ACTION>
        <SYNC_ACTIONS transentityname="WORKORDER" transentitykey="WORKORDERID">
            <ACTION name="INSERT" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="addMatUseTrans"/>
        </SYNC_ACTIONS>
    </ENTITY>
    <ENTITY name="WORKLOG">
        <INDEXES>           
            <INDEX name="IDX_WL_1">WONUM, SITEID</INDEX>
        </INDEXES>
        <COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN displaykey="Y" uniquekey="Y">WORKLOGID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>WONUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>WORKORDERID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>RECORDKEY</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>DESCRIPTION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LONGDESCRIPTION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>CLASS</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>CREATEBY</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>CREATEDATE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LOGTYPE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>SITEID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ORGID</COLUMN>
        </COLUMNS>
        <INIT_ACTION>offline/getMyWorkLogListJson.action</INIT_ACTION>
        <DELTA_ACTION>offline/getDeltaMyWorkLogListJson.action</DELTA_ACTION>
        <SYNC_ACTIONS transentityname="WORKORDER" transentitykey="WORKORDERID">
            <ACTION name="INSERT" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="addWorkLog"/>
        </SYNC_ACTIONS>
    </ENTITY>
    <ENTITY name="FAILUREREPORT">
        <INDEXES>           
            <INDEX name="IDX_FR_1">WORKORDERID</INDEX>
        </INDEXES>  
        <COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN uniquekey="Y">WORKORDERID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN displaykey="Y" >WONUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>FAILURECODE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PROBLEMCODE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>CAUSECODE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>REMEDYCODE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>SITEID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ORGID</COLUMN>
        </COLUMNS>
        <INIT_ACTION>offline/getMyFailureRptListJson.action</INIT_ACTION>
        <DELTA_ACTION>offline/getDeltaMyFailureRptListJson.action</DELTA_ACTION>
        <SYNC_ACTIONS transentityname="WORKORDER" transentitykey="WORKORDERID">
            <ACTION name="EDIT" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="editFailureReport"/>
        </SYNC_ACTIONS>
    </ENTITY>   
    <ENTITY name="MULTIASSETLOCCI">
        <INDEXES>           
            <INDEX name="IDX_MULTI_1">WORKORDERID</INDEX>
        </INDEXES>
        <COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN displaykey="Y" uniquekey="Y">MULTIID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>SEQUENCE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>RECORDKEY</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>WORKORDERID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ASSETNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LOCATION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ROUTE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ROUTESTOP</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>TARGETDESC</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>COMMENTS</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PROGRESS</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>SITEID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ORGID</COLUMN>
        </COLUMNS>
        <INIT_ACTION>offline/getMyMultiAssetLocListJson.action</INIT_ACTION>
        <DELTA_ACTION>offline/getDeltaMyMultiAssetLocListJson.action</DELTA_ACTION>
        <SYNC_ACTIONS transentityname="WORKORDER" transentitykey="WORKORDERID">
            <ACTION name="EDIT_PRG" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="editMultiProgress"/>
        </SYNC_ACTIONS>
    </ENTITY>       
    <ENTITY name="INVENTORY">
        <INDEXES>
            <INDEX name="IDX_INV_1">ITEMNUM, SITEID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_INV_2">ITEMNUM</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_INV_3">ITEMNUM, LOCATION</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_INV_4">SITEID</INDEX>
        </INDEXES>
        <COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN displaykey="Y" uniquekey="Y">INVENTORYID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ITEMNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ITEMSETID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LOCATION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>DESCRIPTION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>CATEGORY</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>MANUFACTURER</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>MODELNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>SITEID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>STATUS</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>STATUSDATE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>BINNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ISSUEUNIT</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ISSUEYTD</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ISSUE1YRAGO</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LASTISSUEDATE</COLUMN>
        </COLUMNS>
        <INIT_ACTION>offline/getAllInventoryJson.action</INIT_ACTION>
        <DELTA_ACTION>offline/getDeltaInventoryListJson.action</DELTA_ACTION>
        <SYNC_ACTIONS transentityname="INVENTORY" transentitykey="INVENTORYID">
            <ACTION name="UPDATE_STATUS" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="updateInventoryStatus"/>
        </SYNC_ACTIONS>
    </ENTITY>           
    <ENTITY name="INVBALANCES">
        <INDEXES>
            <INDEX name="IDX_INVBAL_1">ITEMNUM, SITEID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_INVBAL_2">ITEMNUM</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_INVBAL_3">ITEMNUM, LOCATION</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_INVBAL_4">SITEID</INDEX>
            <INDEX name="IDX_INVBAL_5">BINNUM</INDEX>
        </INDEXES>  
        <COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN uniquekey="Y">INVBALANCESID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN displaykey="Y">ITEMNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ITEMSETID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LOCATION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>DESCRIPTION</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LOTTYPE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ITEMTYPE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>STATUS</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>BINNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>LOTNUM</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>CURBAL</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PHYSCNT</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>PHYSCNTDATE</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>RECONCILED</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>SITEID</COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>ORGID</COLUMN>
        </COLUMNS>
        <INIT_ACTION>offline/getInvBalancesJson.action</INIT_ACTION>
        <DELTA_ACTION>offline/getDeltaInvBalancesJson.action</DELTA_ACTION>
        <SYNC_ACTIONS transentityname="INVBALANCES" transentitykey="INVBALANCESID">
            <ACTION name="UPDATE_PHYSCNT" beanname="OfflineDataSyncAction" methodname="adjustPhysicalCount"/>
        </SYNC_ACTIONS>
    </ENTITY>       
</ENTITY_DEFS>

</EZMAXMOBILE_OFFLINE_PROPERTIES>
```

Here is my run class to unmarshall my xml.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import com.interpro.Objects.*;
public class run {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        File file = new File("C:/Development/workspace/com.interpro.xml/src/XML/offlineconfig.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(EZMAXMOBILE_OFFLINE_PROPERTIES.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        EZMAXMOBILE_OFFLINE_PROPERTIES emm = (EZMAXMOBILE_OFFLINE_PROPERTIES) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println();

      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }


}
```

}

Here are some classes that I generate.

```
package com.interpro.Objects;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
@XmlRootElement(name = "EZMAXMOBILE_OFFLINE_PROPERTIES")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"entity_defs", "selection_defs", "tx_settings", "offline_file_cache"})
public class EZMAXMOBILE_OFFLINE_PROPERTIES {
private String synctime;
private ENTITY_DEFS entity_defs;
public ENTITY_DEFS getEntity_defs() {
    return entity_defs;
}
@XmlElement
public void setEntity_defs(ENTITY_DEFS entity_defs) {
    this.entity_defs = entity_defs;
}

public SELECTION_DEFS getSelection_defs() {
    return selection_defs;
}
@XmlElement
public void setSelection_defs(SELECTION_DEFS selection_defs) {
    this.selection_defs = selection_defs;
}

public TX_SETTINGS getTx_settings() {
    return tx_settings;
}
@XmlElement
public void setTx_settings(TX_SETTINGS tx_settings) {
    this.tx_settings = tx_settings;
}

public OFFLINE_FILE_CACHE getOffline_file_cache() {
    return offline_file_cache;
}
@XmlElement
public void setOffline_file_cache(OFFLINE_FILE_CACHE offline_file_cache) {
    this.offline_file_cache = offline_file_cache;
}

private SELECTION_DEFS selection_defs;
private TX_SETTINGS tx_settings;
private OFFLINE_FILE_CACHE offline_file_cache;

public String getSynctime() {
    return synctime;
}
@XmlAttribute
public void setSynctime(String synctime) {
    this.synctime = synctime;
}
```

}
The EZMAXMOBILE_OFFLINE_PROPERTIES class should generate an Entity_defs object

```
package com.interpro.Objects;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class ENTITY_DEFS {
private ArrayList<ENTITY> entitylist;

public ArrayList<ENTITY> getEntitylist() {
    return entitylist;
}
@XmlElement
public void setEntitylist(ArrayList<ENTITY> entitylist) {
    this.entitylist = entitylist;
}
```

}
Then inside ENTITY_DEFS it should make a list of ENTITY objects.

```
package com.interpro.Objects;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class ENTITY {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}@XmlAttribute
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

private INDEXES indexes;

public INDEXES getIndexes() {
    return indexes;
}@XmlElement
public void setIndexes(INDEXES indexes) {
    this.indexes = indexes;
}

public COLUMNS getColumns() {
    return columns;
}@XmlElement
public void setColumns(COLUMNS columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
}

public INIT_ACTION getInit_action() {
    return init_action;
}@XmlElement
public void setInit_action(INIT_ACTION init_action) {
    this.init_action = init_action;
}

public DELTA_ACTION getDelta_action() {
    return delta_action;
}@XmlElement
public void setDelta_action(DELTA_ACTION delta_action) {
    this.delta_action = delta_action;
}

public SYNC_ACTION getSync_action() {
    return sync_action;
}@XmlElement
public void setSync_action(SYNC_ACTION sync_action) {
    this.sync_action = sync_action;
}

private COLUMNS columns;
private INIT_ACTION init_action;
private DELTA_ACTION delta_action;
private SYNC_ACTION sync_action;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate your object model and then marshal it to get a sense of what JAXB is currently expecting as XML input.  Taking a quick look at your model you are going to need atleast the following:

- Use the `@XmlElement` annotation to specify the element name you wish to map to, since the default name based on your fields/properties isn't going to match.
- Since your collections having grouping elements, you can leverage the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation.

Comment: So what I realized by printing out my xml is that it was a naming convention problem.  I am just unsure if annotation use. I saw that you had a blog on some of this. Would you happen to have a guide that explains in depth of the annotations?

Comment: @DerekParker - The majority of my blog (http://blog.bdoughan.com/) is dedicated to JAXB.  For your use case `@XmlElement`, `@XmlAttribute`, and `@XmlElementWrapper` are going to get you most (if not all) of the way.  My recommendation is start with the root object and work your way down.

Comment: I had run into an issue under a specific case. I have tried to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940267/jaxb-xmlmixed-usage-for-reading-xmlvalue-and-xmlelement. But have still run into a snag. This is my newest post on my current issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858116/xmlmixed-how-to-use