# get text using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

In my app, I'm reading a xml file (with JAXB) but there is times that I have empty segments.

I put some examples

```
<tuv>
    <seg>Unknown: the action taken should always be known</seg>
   </tuv>
```

Here I read well the tag "seg", I can get all text "Unknown: the action taken should always be known" but if this text is like this:

```
<tuv>
    <seg><bpt i="1" x-wb-tag="b1" />Unknown<ept i="1" x-wb-tag="/b1" />: the action taken should always be known</seg>
   </tuv>
```

I don't get anything, my variable is empty and I want to get all text "Unknown: the action taken should always be known"

Could I get this text "Unknown: the action taken should always be known"? (I want this like a string)

Note: my variable's value is a "string"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my question if anybody needs it.

I have used `@XmlMixed` that return a object list.

Here there are more information: [mixed element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940267/jaxb-xmlmixed-usage-for-reading-xmlvalue-and-xmlelement)