# how to use @XmlMixed in jaxB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

how to use @XmlMixed so that I get ESS content value as 'essvalue'.
Now I'm getting ESS content value as null .
please help with @XmlMixed annotation

Ess.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ESS id="9B8FB6C4-9636-11E0-8718-88F89CFF4B22">
        essvalue
       <TITLE id="TEST">Common Core Content Standards</TITLE>
       <TITLE id="TEST2">TEST</TITLE> 
    </ESS>
```

I want to read ESS value 'essvalue' .

and I have ESS java class as

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ESS")
public class ESS
{

    private String id;

    @XmlMixed
    private String content;

    private List<TITLE> TITLE;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [id = "+id+", TITLE = "+TITLE+"]";
    }

    @XmlElementRef(name="ESS",type=TITLE.class)
    public List<TITLE> getTITLE() {
        return TITLE;
    }

    public void setTITLE(List<TITLE> tITLE) {
        TITLE = tITLE;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940267/jaxb-xmlmixed-usage-for-reading-xmlvalue-and-xmlelement

Comment: @Mahi I solved this issue by changing `private String content` to `List<String >  content `